# Angular Reactive Form - How to use FormArray with FormGroup(s)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am trying to mimic my model in my reactive form. I've set up a few FormGroups to "nest" things that make sense according to my model. I'm having trouble setting up my component to *read* the values--which suggests that I likely don't have my template set up correctly either.

Depending if I am editing an existing location or creating a new one,

```
@Input() location: ILocation;
```

could be `undefined`. Currently, I am only focused on working with an existing location, so I know `location` has value.

```
// location.model.ts

name: string;
...
messaging: [
    {
        email: {
            fromName: string;
            fromAddress: string;
        };
    }
];
...
createdAt?: string;
updatedAt?: string;
deletedAt?: string;
```

In my template I am using `ngClass` to give the user validation feedback:

```
// location.commponent.html

<div formGroupName="messaging">
    <div formGroupName="email">
        ...
        <div [ngClass]="form.get(['messaging', 'email', 'fromName'])!.errors && (form.get(['messaging', 'email', 'fromName'])!.dirty || form.get(['messaging', 'email', 'fromName'])!.touched) ? 'red' : 'green'">
            <input name="fromName"/>
        </div>
        <!-- fromAddress -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In my component, I am passing the model in with input binding, then setting up my form group(s) and form fields like this:

```
// location.component.ts

@Input() location: ILocation; 

form: FormGroup;

...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({name: new FormControl(this.location.name, [Validators.required]),
    messaging: new FormGroup({
    email: new FormGroup({
        fromName: new FormControl(this.location.messaging[0].email.fromName, [Validators.required]),
        fromAddress: new FormControl(this.location.messaging[0].email.fromAddress, [Validators.required]),
        }),
    }),
}
```

The error I am seeing is:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

If I log out what is in the component:

```
console.log('messaging: ', this.location.messaging);

// email: {fromName: 'No Reply <noreply@example.com>', fromAddress: 'noreply@example.com'}
```

I've tried various methods of `messaging['email']` or `messaging.email` `messaging[0]` but I can't find the correct path.

I am also not sure if I am using the `get()` method correctly in my template.

How can I set up my form to correctly read/present the data?

**Update:**

Not surprisingly, a big problem I was having was sending the wrong shape of data back.

In the end, this is the JSON I am trying to create:

```
[{"email":{"fromName":"No Reply <noreply@example.com>","fromAddress":"noreply@example.com"}}]
```

It looks like I need to use [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) to send the proper shape:

```
messaging: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
        email: new FormGroup({
            fromName: new FormControl(this.location.messaging[0].email.fromName, [Validators.required]),
            fromAddress: new FormControl(this.location.messaging[0].email.fromAddress, [Validators.required]),
        }),
    }),
]),
```

This is causing some trouble in my template as I'm currently doing this: `form.get('messaging[0].email.fromAddress')`

Resulting in:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'messaging -> email'

I think I need to somehow loop through the `FormArray`. This really isn't a dynamic array though. I'll always have `email` and only `fromName` and `fromAddress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the `FormArray` as the `messaging` is an array.

You need to iterate every element in `FormArray` via `*ngFor` and provide the index (`i`):

```
form.get(['messaging', i, 'email', 'fromName'])
```

The complete *flow* of your template form from parent FormGroup to `fromName` `FormControl` would be:

> form (`FormGroup`) --> messaging (`FormArray`) --> i (`FormGroup`) --> email (`FormGroup`) --> fromName (`FormControl`)

The HTML template should be:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div
    formArrayName="messaging"
    *ngFor="let control of messaging.controls; let i = index"
  >
    <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
      <div formGroupName="email">
        ...
        <div
          [ngClass]="
            form.get(['messaging', i, 'email', 'fromName'])!.errors &&
            (form.get(['messaging', i, 'email', 'fromName'])!.dirty ||
              form.get(['messaging', i, 'email', 'fromName'])!.touched)
              ? 'red'
              : 'green'
          "
        >
          <input formControlName="fromName" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <!-- fromAddress -->
          <input formControlName="fromAddress" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
get messaging(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('messaging') as FormArray;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tjix8k?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Oh my goodness, this was so helpful to get me over the hump. Thank you so much for your explanation!

Comment: If only want to change the apparence of the input, Angular add the class ng-invalid, ng-touched... (see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes)) automatically. So you can simply use this class in your .css, e.g. `input.ng-invalid.ng-touched{border-color:red}` and you can not fight with ngClass. NOTE: when the selector [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) will was full supported by the navigators we can transform also the parent of the input